# Converting DOS text files to Unicode using Python

Tags: python, text, unicode, codepages

I am trying to write a Python application for converting old DOS code page text files to their Unicode equivalent. Now, I have done this before using Turbo Pascal by creating a look-up table and I'm sure the same can be done using a Python dictionary. My question is: *How do I index into the dictionary to find the character I want to convert and send the equivalent Unicode to a Unicode output file?*

I realize that this may be a repeat of a similar question but nothing I searched for here quite matches my question.

Comment: Actually, you didn't post a question. You posted a problem.  SO is more about answering questions. To get a response, I suggest trying something and if it doesn't work, post your code and ask for advice.

Comment: Do you really want to to the lookup yourself? Python has lots of build in encodings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Answer (score 4):

Python has the codecs to do the conversions:

```
#!python3

# Test file with bytes 0-255.
with open('dos.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(range(256)))

# Read the file and decode using code page 437 (DOS OEM-US).
# Write the file as UTF-8 encoding ("Unicode" is not an encoding)
# UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 are encodings that support all Unicode codepoints.

with open('dos.txt',encoding='cp437') as infile:
    with open('unicode.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard buildin `decode` method of `bytes` objects:

```
with open('dos.txt', 'r', encoding='cp437') as infile, \
        open('unicode.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: In Python 2 the default encoding for `unicode.txt` will be `ascii` and in Python 3 it will be `locale.getpreferredencoding()` (On US Windows, `cp1252`).  So this won't work unless you use Python 3 and an OS that defaults to UTF-8, for example.  Neither support the full range of cp437 characters.